# I just want to sort the data from the server side using usort descending...in order to get user_id in first position Hw is it possible

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsjYc.png)
In this image user_id is in the last position i just need to usort this how is it works..!!

Comment: You want  to sort it by user_id?

Comment: You can use lodash which gives you good feasibility to work on arrays _.orderBy(yourArray, ['user_id'], ['asc']);

Comment: it's impossible. keys's ordering in `{}` aka Hash is never guaranteed.